# Python dictionary with memory of keys that were accessed?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a data structure that behaves like a dictionary with one added functionality which is to keep track of which keys have been "consumed". Please note that I can't just pop the values as they are being reused.

The structure should support these three cases, i.e. mark the key as consumed when accessed as:

```
if key in d:
    ...
d[key]
d.get(key)
```

This is what I have written:

```
class DictWithMemory(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.memory = set()
        return super(DictWithMemory, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.memory.add(key)
        return super(DictWithMemory, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        self.memory.add(key)
        return super(DictWithMemory, self).__contains__(key)

    def get(self, key, d=None):
        self.memory.add(key)
        return super(DictWithMemory, self).get(key, d)

    def unused_keys(self):
        """
        Returns the list of unused keys.
        """
        return set(self.keys()).difference(self.memory)
```

As I am not very familiar with the internals of dict, is there a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: how often do you use `unused_keys()`? if you decorated the setter to add keys to a set and getter to try to remove keys from this set, it might have better perfomance - not sure about the **elegance** part, thought

Comment: Aside: why should `unused_keys` return a list? It has no intrinsic ordering, so it makes sense for it to return a set.

Comment: @Thomas K: For the sake of symmetry, `keys` returning a list.

Comment: I have to say that if I were to come across a dictionary whose observable state got modified by `in`, `.get()` etc, I would find that *extremely* surprising. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @deathApril: I use `unused keys` only once, after I am done accessing the dictionary. So I am not very concerned by the performance of this one method. Replaced **elegant** with **better**.

Comment: keys() returning a list is kind of an accident of history, because sets were a relatively recent addition. In Python 3, `d.keys()` returns an iterator, not a list.

Comment: `unused_keys` can be simpler if you reverse the expression: `return list(self.memory.difference(self.iterkeys()))`.

Comment: @aix: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "observable state"?

Comment: @Thomas K: `unused_keys` now returns a set.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Modified the code based on your comment.

Comment: And I just realised set difference is not symmetric. Derp.

Comment: Personally I don't think checking if `key in d` should count as an access since it doesn't look up or change the associated value.

Comment: @martineau: It makes sense for what I need to do. I am not trying to solve a general problem here.

Comment: @badzil: Well, in that case another plus for chepner's answer is that it makes the affected methods easily changed. Sometimes it's worth the effort to solve the more general problem instead of the just the specific one -- because you end up with something more flexible and reusable.

Comment: @badzil: I guess what bothers me about including membership testing is the danger that it would count key checks for non-existent key as "consumption" of them, even though they're not even in the mapping.

Comment: @martineau: This is a valid concern which could cause problems if someone rewrite DictWithMemory.unused_keys in a different way.

Comment: @badzil: True, however immediately after `if key1 not in dwm: dwm[key1] = value`, `key1` would be considered used, but following just a `dwm[key2] = value` statement, `key2` would not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that abstracts everything away inside a metaclass. I'm not sure if this is really any more elegant, but it does provide some amount of encapsulation should you change your mind about how to store the used keys:

```
class KeyRememberer(type):

    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        cls = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict)

        # Define init that creates the set of remembered keys
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.memory = set()
            return super(cls, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__init__ = __init__

        # Decorator that stores a requested key in the cache
        def remember(f):
            def _(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
                self.memory.add(key)
                return f(self, key, *args, **kwargs)
            return _

        # Apply the decorator to each of the default implementations
        for method_name in [  '__getitem__', '__contains__', 'get' ]:
            m = getattr(cls, method_name)
            setattr(cls, method_name, remember(m))

        return cls


class DictWithMemory(dict):

    # A metaclass that ensures the object
    # has a set called 'memory' as an attribute,
    # which is updated on each call to __getitem__,
    # __contains__, or get.
    __metaclass__ = KeyRememberer

    def unused_keys(self):
        """
        Returns the list of unused keys.
        """
        print "Used", self.memory
        return list(set(super(DictWithMemory,
                              self).keys()).difference(self.memory))
```

Comment: I like your use of a metaclass to limit that allows a dynamic configuration of which methods are considered "consumers".

Comment: I agree with @badzil's comment and think maybe it should go even further and allow the its clients to define or override which methods are considered consumers -- at feature I believe could easily be added.